# How to center text at bottom of table cell?

Tags: html, css, centering, css-tables

http://jsfiddle.net/myxzh/

```
 <ul>          
       <li><a href="news.asp">Hello</a></li>
       <li><a href="contact.asp">Hello</a></li>
       <li><a href="about.asp">Hello</a></li>
 </ul>

 ul {
display: table;
table-layout: fixed;
width: 100%;
padding:0;
 }

 li {
display: table-cell;
height: 150px;
border: 1px solid black;
position: relative;
text-align: center;

}

ul li a {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
text-align: center;
}
```

I'm trying to center this text in the middle of each table cell but as you can see the text is not quite centered. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`vertical-align:middle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/vertical-align).

```
ul {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    padding:0;
}

li {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;    
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/myxzh/5/)

Comment: I think he wants to align his text at the vertical middle of his cells : "I'm trying to center this text in the middle of each table cell".

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS in the "li" section :

```
li {
   ...
   vertical-align: middle;    
}
```